# Does Wallpaper(and lock screen wallpaper) size affect performance?

Tags: windows-10-mobile, lumia-640-xl, performance

The default wallpapers provided are low in size,preferably less than 1Mb, and resolution.

But if we add high resolution wallpaper with more Mb and resolution, will it affect performance?

And what about the transparency?